# How to throttle two versions of javascript files in (using) webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

Simple scenario

- compiledJsfile-{hashCode1}
- compiledJsfile-{hashCode2}

I currently load (throttle) these two javascript versions of different code but same project in production by changing the hashCode in a CMS based platform.
the script tag looks like

```
<script src="src/dist/compiledJsfile-{hashCode1}" />
```

in this current javascript file i look for the hash change (prev v/s new, old is the current JS file hashcode) and replace the script tag with new hashCode (hashCode2)

```
Example code:

if (scriptTag.src.includes('/src/dist/javascript/compiledJsfile-')) {
        const newTag = document.createElement('script');

        newTag.type = 'text/javascript';
        newTag.src = `/src/dist/javascript/compiledJsfile-${hashCode2}.js`;
        newTag.async = true;

        scriptTag.parentNode.removeChild(scriptTag);
        document.body.appendChild(newTag);
        console.log('Generating the newHashVersion script ', throttledHashVersion);
    }
```

Is there a different of doing this using the webpack configs ? Even before the JS is loaded onto the page and just do it in the webpack configs?

Comment: Are you including that script tag in html file?

Comment: yes @NenadVracar

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin/ that will always generate new html file in the build folder with updated js filename?

Comment: i just want to throttle the js experience. something like 50% of users get old code and 50% users get new code. this is just for convenience. i cannot do that using html plugin. can i ?